# React Exposing DOM Refs to Parent Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I'm learning from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) but don't get the line below

```
inputRef={el => this.inputElement = el}
```

Why is there a `= el` at the end? Isn't `inputRef` just supposed to be a function to grab a reference to the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use ref in 2 ways, first way is pass a string value as a ref and access the component as:

```
inputRef="input"
...
myInput = this.refs.input
```

But this is an old way and it may be deprecated in next versions.
The second way is to pass a function to ref, which fired when a component is mounted and ready to work. Also, this function will receive the target element as a parameter.

To clarify this moment let's write the same code in ES5:

```
inputRef={ function(input) {_this.inputElement = input;}
```

So, in this case, you've added inputElement key to parent component that contains the input. And you can access it via `this.inputElement`